# Get .each() prev element height

Tags: jquery, loops, each

How can I get the height of the previous element in the loop? Here is my code

```
jQuery(".wrap").each(function(index, element) {
  var id = jQuery(this).data('id');
  var wrapper_height = jQuery('.wrap_' + id).outerHeight(true); 
});
```

i need the height of first element which iterated and then all previous elements.

I have two div's of class name **wrap** i need the height of first **wrap** item when it's iterated and same for next (when third element is iterating in loop i need second element height).

when 4th item is iterating in each i need third iterated item height.

Markup: `<div class="wrap wrap_283" data-type="offer_bar" id="283" data-id="283" data-trigger_method="auto" data-auto_method="im" data-timer_date="2" style="">Some content</div> <div class="wrap wrap_284" data-type="offer_bar" id="284" data-id="283" data-trigger_method="auto" data-auto_method="im" data-timer_date="2" style="">Some content</div>`

Any help ?

Comment: all previous elements in the document or all previous children?

Comment: Show your markup, please, and update to describe exactly which element you want to select.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: there is no markup jet...

Comment: Check now is it fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider capturing the previous item with:

`var prev = jQuery(".wrap")[index - 1];`

**Edit:**

Because of your markup, you could go with:

`var prev = jQuery(this).prev()`
[docs](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)